# Convert function with for/while loop into Pandas dataframe.apply(lambda ...: ...) method if there is a change in each iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I am looking for a way to convert structure:

```
for ... in dataframe:
   while ...:
      if ...:
         do smth
   if ...:
      do smth
```

to

```
dataframe.apply(lambda ...: ...)
```

Here is example of function with for/while loop:

```
d_test = {
    'name' : ['South Beach', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Ant', 'Big Dog', 'Beach', 'Dear', 'Cat', 'Fish', 'Dry Fish'],
    'cluster_number' : [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2]
}

df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)

from rapidfuzz import fuzz

df_test = df_test.sort_values(['cluster_number', 'name'])
df_test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_test['id'] = 0

def loop_in_cluster(index, row, df_test, index_, row_, is_i_used, i):
    while index_ < len(df_test) and df_test.loc[index, 'cluster_number'] == df_test.loc[index_, 'cluster_number'] and df_test.loc[index_, 'id'] == 0:     
        if row['name'] == df_test.loc[index_, 'name'] or fuzz.ratio(row['name'], df_test.loc[index_, 'name']) > 50:
            df_test.loc[index_,'id'] = i
            is_i_used = True
        index_ += 1
    return df_test, is_i_used
    
i = 1
is_i_used = False
for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    row_ = row
    index_ = index
    df_test, is_i_used = loop_in_cluster(index, row, df_test, index_, row_, is_i_used, i)
    if is_i_used == True:
        i += 1
        is_i_used = False
```

And here is my attempt to use `dataframe.apply()` method:

```
i = 1
df_test.apply(lambda row: loop_in_cluster(i=i+1, index=row.name, row=row, df_test=df_test, index_=index, row_ = row, is_i_used=False) if is_i_used==True else loop_in_cluster(i=i, index=row.name, row=row, df_test=df_test, index_= index, row_=row, is_i_used=True), axis=1)
```

but I am getting: `StopIteration:` error in output. I tired other methods such as pandas `groupby.GroupBy` method but it seems that `apply` method is more closer to what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't think you can do `i+=1` as an argument in your method. Also, your error is because the `i+=1` (positional) argument comes after the `index_ `, `row`, and `is_i_used ` (keyword) arguments. Rearrange the ordering so that the `i` argument is before all of the keyword args.

Comment: @cmauck10 thanks, but now I am getting `StopIteration:` error.